# How can I create images with grunt?

Tags: gruntjs

I need to create some 1x1 pixel images in different colors and different opacity in gruntjs. I used this tool too create the 1x1 pixel images: http://www.1x1px.me/

Is there a plugin which create the images?

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/) will help you most. Just try to create needed types of images in console then wrap this commands by [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) or [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) tasks. It's also easy to create custom task based on that: create the function to generate parameters then pass them to ImageMagick.